permanently setting RX TX Buffer for an interface
I've tried several things and I'm just typing this there so that someone else does not spend as much time as I did on this.
I had success with this:
sudo -i    
mkdir /etc/networkd-dispatcher/configured.d
nano /etc/networkd-dispatcher/configured.d/set-buffer

## With this content

#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/ethtool -G enp24s0f0np0 rx 2047 tx 2047
/usr/sbin/ethtool -G enp24s0f1np1 rx 2047 tx 2047

Please let me know if there is a better way.
Best
inDane

This is a question and answer site. I see what appears to be an Answer without a question. This gets deleted by the Mods. If you have a question and this is the answer to it post the question. After you can use the answer your own question option to give this answer.
